# in VRPTW, how to make the constraints soft instead of being strictly hard when doing the routing?

Tags: constraints, or-tools, vehicle-routing

as the title indicates, when incorporating time window, vehicle constraints for nodes, in some scenarios the constraints are too strict and I am unable to produce an output.
How can I make the constraints optional or soft but reflect that in a cost (utility) function, so I can rank my solutions?

Used combinations of constraints to solve the VRPTW but it turned out to be unsolvable, how to make it solvable but reflect the degree to which I am violating the constraints?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use

```cpp
void RoutingDimension::SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(
  int64_t index,
  int64_t upper_bound,
  int64_t coefficient);
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/f460e9b0fcd444c37878ec64be9822d40fb375f4/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2905-L2914

and/or

```cpp
void RoutingDimension::SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(
  int64_t index,
  int64_t upper_bound,
  int64_t coefficient);
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/f460e9b0fcd444c37878ec64be9822d40fb375f4/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2927-L2937

note: Supposing you have

```
0 ---- [min_hard -- [min_soft --- max_soft] -- max_hard] --- vehicle_capacity
```

You could use (in Python)

```py
index = manager.NodeToIndex(42)
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(min_hard, max_hard)
penalty = 100
time_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(index, min_soft, penalty)
time_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, max_soft, penalty)
```

if vehicle visit `index` at `max_soft + k` then the objective will have `k * penalty` extra cost.